# if 2 columns in one row match another row, treat as duplicate entry MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

For example, `'Column_1'` may have duplicate entries, and `'Column_2'` may have duplicate entries, but a row may not contain the same `'Column_1' AND 'Column_2'` values as another row. Would like to return a duplicate entry error in this case.

I know how to do this is PHP but am trying to write the script in SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper method here would be to create a unique index across those two columns. Then the database will return a key violation when attempting to insert a duplicate.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE KEY `uniq_column1_column2` (`Column_1`, `Column_2`);
```

Here's a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/631373

Comment: thanks, it seemed to work without naming it as in your unedited example. is naming the unique key necessary?

Comment: @chuckieDub Not necessary - MySQL will assign a name if you do not, which you'll see if you do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`. If you have several keys defined, you may want to come up with a naming convention for them...